Convert rows into columns - hive
I have a table with each log entry as rows. I need to convert rows into columns for 7 days.
I am trying to achieve this in hive.
Input:
Id date row
1 mar-21 123
1 mar-22 1234
2 mar-21 234
2 mar-22 345
2 mar-23 456
3 mar-21 789

Expected output:
Id date1 row1 date2 row2 date3 row3
1 mar-22 1234 mar-21 123 null null
2 mar-23 456 mar-22 345 mar-21 234
3 mar-21 789 null null null null

